# Why is this OCaml code so slow?

Tags: ocaml

I am a OCaml newbie. I wrote a simple program in OCaml to generate the fair and square numbers ( a number that is a palindrome and the square of another palindrome, 
more details here: https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/2270488/dashboard#s=p2 
 ) as follows:

Update 1: Optimized algorithm (takes around 20 secs on my laptop):

```
open Printf;;

let rec _is_palindrome s i j =
  i >= j || 
  (s.[i] = s.[j] && 
      _is_palindrome s (i + 1) (j - 1))
;;

let is_palindrome s =
  let sl = String.length s in
    sl > 0 && (_is_palindrome s 0 (sl - 1))
;;

let rec del_zeros s =
  let sl = String.length s in
    if (sl < 1) then
      s
    else
      (if s.[0] = '0' then
         del_zeros (String.sub s 1 (sl - 1))
       else
         s
      )
;;

let c2i c =
  Char.code c - Char.code '0'
;;

let i2c i =
  Char.chr (i + Char.code '0')
;;

(* only for finding fair and square numbers *)
let square s =
  let slen = String.length s in
    if slen < 1 then
      ""
    else
      let reslen = 2 * slen in
      let t = ref 0 in
        t := 0;
        (* fast check *)
        (let i = reslen/2 in
           for j = (slen - 1) downto 0 do
             if (i - 1 - j) >= 0 && (i - 1 - j) < slen then
               t := !t + (c2i s.[j]) * (c2i s.[i - 1 - j]);
           done;
           if !t > 9 then
             (* jump out *)
             raise (Invalid_argument "carry");
        ); 
        (let res = String.make reslen '0' in
           (* do the square cal now *)
           for i = (reslen - 1) downto 1 do
             t := 0;
             for j = (slen - 1) downto 0 do
               if (i - 1 - j) >= 0 && (i - 1 - j) < slen then
                 t := !t + (c2i s.[j]) * (c2i s.[i - 1 - j]);
             done;
             if !t > 9 then
               (* jump out *)
               raise (Invalid_argument "carry");
             res.[i] <- i2c !t;
           done;
           del_zeros res
        );
;;

let rec check_fs fsns p =
  try let sq = square p in
    if (is_palindrome sq) then
      sq :: fsns
    else
      fsns
  with Invalid_argument "carry" ->
    fsns
;;

(* build the fair and square number list *)
(* dfs *)
let rec create_fair_square_nums fsns p sum max_num_digs =
  let l = String.length p in
    if l > max_num_digs || sum > 9 then
          fsns
    else
      let fsns = create_fair_square_nums fsns ("0" ^ p ^ "0") sum max_num_digs in
      let fsns = create_fair_square_nums fsns ("1" ^ p ^ "1") (sum + 1) max_num_digs in
      let fsns = create_fair_square_nums fsns ("2" ^ p ^ "2") (sum + 4)  max_num_digs in
      let fsns = create_fair_square_nums fsns ("3" ^ p ^ "3") (sum + 9) max_num_digs in
      let fsns = check_fs fsns p in
        fsns
;;

let rec print_fsns fsns =
  List.iter (fun s -> printf "%s " s) fsns;
  printf "\n"
;;

let num_str_cmp s1 s2 =
  let len1 = String.length s1 in
  let len2 = String.length s2 in
    match (len1 - len2) with
      | 0 ->
          String.compare s1 s2
      | cmp -> cmp
;;

(* works *)

let max_dig = 51;;

let fsns = 
  let fsns = create_fair_square_nums [] "" 0 max_dig in
  let fsns = create_fair_square_nums fsns "0" 0 max_dig in
  let fsns = create_fair_square_nums fsns "1" 1 max_dig in
  let fsns = create_fair_square_nums fsns "2" 4 max_dig in
    create_fair_square_nums fsns "3" 9 max_dig
;;

let fsns = List.sort num_str_cmp fsns;;

print_fsns fsns;;
```

My original code (naive solution, too slow):

```
open Printf;;

let rec _is_palindrome s i j =
  if i < j then
    if s.[i] = s.[j] then
      _is_palindrome s (i + 1) (j - 1)
    else
      false
  else
    true
;;

let is_palindrome s =
  if (String.length s < 1) then
    false
  else
    _is_palindrome s 0 ((String.length s) - 1)
;;

let rec del_zeros s =
  let sl = String.length s in
    if (sl < 1) then
      s
    else
      (if s.[0] = '0' then
         del_zeros (String.sub s 1 (sl - 1))
       else
         s
      )
;;

let c2i c =
  Char.code c - Char.code '0'
;;

let i2c i =
  Char.chr (i + Char.code '0')
;;

(* only positive number *)
let square s =
  (* including the carry dig *)
  let slen = String.length s in
  let res = (
    if slen > 0 then
      let reslen = 2 * slen in
      let res = String.make reslen '0' in
      let t = ref 0 in
        for i = (reslen - 1) downto 1 do
          t := c2i (res.[i]);
          for j = (slen - 1) downto 0 do
            if (i - 1 - j) >= 0 && (i - 1 - j) < slen then
              (t := !t + (c2i s.[j]) * (c2i s.[i - 1 - j]);
          (* printf "%d, %d: %d\n" j (i - 1 - j) !t; *) )
          done;
          (* printf "%d: %d\n" i !t; *)
          if !t > 9 then
            (res.[i - 1] <- 
             Char.chr (Char.code res.[i - 1] + (!t / 10));
             t := !t mod 10
            );
          res.[i] <- i2c !t;
        done;
        res;
        else
          ""
  ) in
    (* printf "square %s -> %s\n" s res; *)
    del_zeros res
;;

let extend_palindrome new_ps n = 
  ("0" ^ n ^ "0") :: 
  ("1" ^ n ^ "1") :: 
  ("2" ^ n ^ "2") :: 
  ("3" ^ n ^ "3") :: 
  new_ps
;;

let rec extend_palindromes new_ps ps = 
  match ps with
    | [] -> new_ps
    | h :: t -> 
        let new_ps = extend_palindrome new_ps h in
          extend_palindromes new_ps t
;;

let rec check_fs fsns ps =
  match ps with
    | [] -> fsns
    | h :: t -> 
        let sq = square h in
          if (is_palindrome sq) then
            check_fs (sq :: fsns) t
          else 
            check_fs fsns t
;;

(* build the fair and square number list *)
let rec create_fair_square_nums fsns ps max_num_digs =
  match ps with
    | h :: t ->
        if String.length h > max_num_digs then
          fsns
        else
          let ps = extend_palindromes [] ps in
          let fsns = check_fs fsns ps in
            create_fair_square_nums fsns ps max_num_digs
    | [] ->
        raise (Invalid_argument "fsn should not be []")
;;

let rec print_fsns fsns =
  List.iter (fun s -> printf "%s " s) fsns;
  printf "\n"
;;

let num_str_cmp s1 s2 =
  let len1 = String.length s1 in
  let len2 = String.length s2 in
    match (len1 - len2) with
      | 0 ->
          String.compare s1 s2
      | cmp -> cmp
;;

(* works *)

let max_dig = 50;;

let fsns = 
  let fsns0 = create_fair_square_nums [] [""] max_dig in
  let fsns1 = create_fair_square_nums [] ["0"; "1"; "2"; "3"] max_dig in
    (* print_fsns fsns0;
    print_fsns fsns1; *)
    ["0"; "1"; "4"; "9"] @ fsns0 @ fsns1
;;

(* print_fsns fsns;; *)

let fsns = List.sort num_str_cmp fsns;;

print_fsns fsns;;
```

This code generates the fair and square numbers which is within 10^100.

This code should have some (or many) problems regarding the performance. It run for more than 30 mins before I killed it. When max_dig = 14 it finishes quickly (< 1min).

Any suggestion on improving this code or criticism to it are both welcome.

Comment: This isn't an OCaml question. Your algorithm is just too slow for the large2 input. I suggest you read the [contest analysis](http://code.google.com/codejam/contest/2270488/dashboard#s=a&a=2) from Google.

Comment: Thanks @cygin . Yes, the algorithm has problem. The optimized one works great (< 20 secs) now.

Answer (score 4):

This is probably one issue among many others (and possibly neglectible
in your use case, you should profile to find that out), but this code
snippet already has algorithmic issues:

```
let rec del_zeros s =
  let sl = String.length s in
    if (sl < 1) then
      s
    else
      (if s.[0] = '0' then
         del_zeros (String.sub s 1 (sl - 1))
       else
         s
      )
;;
```

String.sub is linear in the length argument (in memory,
therefore time), so the whole function is quadratic: `del_zeros
(String.make 50_000 '0')` is probably going to be slow.

To write this code efficiently you should collect the kept characters
in a list accumulator, accumulating the total length as you go, and
finally create a string of the right size and write those characters
in it.

As an approximation, the natural code using `Buffer` would already be
reasonably efficient (that's what I would recommend writing for usual
applications, but maybe not in an algorithmic contest if that's part
of the critical path):

```
let del_zeros s =
  let buf = Buffer.create (String.length s) in
  for i = 0 to (String.length s) - 1 do
    if s.[i] <> '0' then Buffer.add_char buf s.[i]
  done;
  Buffer.contents buf
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I tried it in the program but it turns to be a little bit (0.5 sec) slower with `Buffer`. I guess this is because most `s`s in the program have only 1 leading '0'. But I am not very sure this is the reason.

Answer (score 3):

When dealing with big integers, you can use the `Big_int` module which will be faster than your custom implementation of square (and it will also save you a lot of time writing the code).

Also, it is bad style to write `if a then b else false` where you can just simply write `a && b`.

Comment: Great suggestion about the `a && b`. It shortens the code significantly in the updated code. Thanks! I considered `Big_int`. But implementing a customized one (square) allows optimizations specific to the problem (e.g. jumps out if there is no need to continue the calculation. My method using exception may be too costly). So I chose to implement one by myself.